# The development server returned response error code 500 in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bundler

[image: emulator console]
[image: Terminal console]

I can not figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Please edit the question and show me your code.

Comment: Code MUST be posted as text not pictures! [mcve]

Comment: It's not the code, it's terminal output

Answer (score 1):

you can use this line

```
react-native start
```

Answer (score 0):

## Kill current processes

```
sudo killall node -9
```

## Start React - Native

```
react-native start // another terminal
```

## Run

```
open your app or react-native run-android or react-native run-ios
```